# Mapbox caching in ios app

Tags: ios, mapbox

In the application I have some `mapViews`, and I want to support offline mode(caching). So: user installed app, the main screen contains `mapView` and it should cache it. Then user turns off the Wi-Fi and 3G, and tries to take a look at another `mapView` ( another `viewController`). It's not downloaded now. But the main screen's map is okay. Am I in the wrong way to cache?

the code for configuring the map is the same:

```
[[RMConfiguration sharedInstance] setAccessToken:@"pk.***"];
     RMMapboxSource *tileSource = [[RMMapboxSource alloc] initWithMapID:kMapboxMapID];
    [tileSource setCacheable:YES];
    [self.mapView.tileCache setBackgroundCacheDelegate:self];
    [self.mapView.tileCache beginBackgroundCacheForTileSource:tileSource southWest:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(55.767363, 37.592843) northEast:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(55.799801, 37.671229) minZoom:11 maxZoom:11];
    self.mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andTilesource:tileSource];
    self.mapView.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
```

Comment: when user is offline, and tries to get access to the map, the tile source is always "nil".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't using `RMTileCache`'s download methods to pre-fetch an area of the map, this will only work if the map area trying to be viewed in the second view controller is the same as that already viewed in the first.

Comment: Yes, but I have just added the methods. I don't understand how can I get the tileSource, it's always 'nil'. I can't find any examples of caching..